# Saving text from multiple UITextFields that have the same property name

Tags: ios, uitextfield

So I have a view controller that I created completely programmatically, I didn't use  storyboard or a nib file. In it, I have a button, `addNew` that when pressed, it creates two UITextfields, one for a number, the other for a product, and places it where the "Add New"button was, and moves the button down. Instead of explaining it, here's some code :

```
-(IBAction)addProduct:(id)sender{
    self.numOfProducts += 1;
    //To keep track of how many times the button was pressed
    NSLog(@"New Product Added");
    NSLog(@"# of products: %d", self.numOfMaterials);

    //The number textfield
    self.numOfProduct = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.addNew.frame.origin.x, self.addNew.frame.origin.y, 70.0, 30.0)];
    self.numOfProduct.delegate = self;
    self.numOfProduct.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.numOfProduct setPlaceholder:@"#"];
    self.numOfProduct.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
    self.numOfProduct.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; 
    //Added doneToolbar to close keypad
    UIToolbar *doneToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [doneToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneNumPad)],
                       nil]];
    [doneToolbar sizeToFit];
    self.numOfMaterialNeeded.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar;

    //Product text field, places it next to numOfProduct text field
    self.product = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.numOfProduct.frame.origin.x + 80, self.numOfProduct.frame.origin.y, 200.0, 30.0)];
    self.product.delegate = self;
    self.product.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.product setPlaceholder:@"Product"];
    self.product.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
    self.product.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.product.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    self.product.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    self.product.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

    //Places addNew below the newly created text fields
    [self.addNew setFrame:CGRectMake(self.addNewMaterial.frame.origin.x, self.addNewMaterial.frame.origin.y + (self.addNewMaterial.frame.size.height + 10), self.addNewMaterial.frame.size.width, self.addNewMaterial.frame.size.height)];

    // add text fields to the UIScrollView
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.numOfMaterialNeeded];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.material];
}

//Called when done button is pressed for numOfProduct text field
-(void)doneNumPad{
    [self.numOfProduct resignFirstResponder];
    [self.product becomeFirstResponder];
    //Save num in an array
    [self.saveNumOfProduct addObject:self.numOfProduct.text];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.saveNumOfProduct count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@ of ___", [self.saveNumOfProduct objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    //Save product in an array
    if (textField == self.product) { //
        [self.saveNameOfProduct addObject:self.product.text];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The code is working well and fine, BUT, I realized, if I have the `self.numOfProduct` textField as the first responder, and instead of pressing "Done", I press the `self.product` textField right away, it won't save the `self.numOfProduct.text`, same with the `self.product.text`, it won't save unless I press "Done". How can I do it so that I can efficiently save the text from the textfield property, no matter how many textfields I have on the screen? Is it possible? I appreciate any feedback! And if I haven't been clear enough, lemme know and I'll clear up whatever needs clearing!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer! A lot easier than I thought it would be, I completely forgot about the `(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` function. All I had to do was save the text in that function, and it saves every time the textfield becomes the responder to another field OR when I press the done button.

Comment: And I've just figured out that tags work wonderfully with this!! even if the uitextfield have the same property name, their tags are different!